# Mapping object keys and values into another object

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

How would you implement a mapping function, from an object keys to another object that has a property with that specific key, preserving the object structure

For example, given this input object:

```
{
    person: {
        first_name: "fn",
        last_name: "ln",
        address: {
            city: "c",
            street: "s",
        },
        movies: [
            {
                title: "movie1"
            },
            {
                title: "movie2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the result should be:

```
{
    name: "person",
    children: [
        {
            name: "first_name"
        },
        {
            name: "last_name"
        },
        {
            name: "address",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "city"                  
                },
                {
                    name: "street"                  
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "movies",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "title"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried with some recursive object traversals but the implementation was really ugly. I feel that there is an easier way to handle it

Comment: Can you show your attempt please?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I get to the workstation

Comment: What if there is another key with `person`?

Comment: There won't be. But if it is, it should override the first

Comment: @Fraction there won't be, data is already sanitized and formatted properly. Input  structure does not vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using recursion. Create a function which takes an entry as input. Entry is an array of two element which contains key value pair for an object. `[key,value]`

```js
const obj = { person: { first_name: "fn", last_name: "ln", address: { city: "c", street: "s", }, movies: [ { title: "movie1" }, { title: "movie2" } ] } }

function getKeys(entry){
  let obj = {
    name:entry[0],
    children:[]
  }
  const { children } = obj
  let val = entry[1]
  for(let k in val){
    if(Array.isArray(val[k])){
      children.push(getKeys([k,val[k][1]]));
    }
    else if(typeof val[k] === "object"){
      children.push(getKeys([k,val[k]]))
    }
    else children.push({name:k})
  }
  if(!obj.children.length) delete obj.children;
  return obj
}
console.log(getKeys(Object.entries(obj)[0]))
```